# Property does not exist error in checkstyle configuration file

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I create an Android project using Android Studio. In the `build.gradle` of the app add:

```
apply from: '../config/quality.gradle'
```

Then I create the `config` dir with two files: `quality.gradle` like:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile file("${project.rootDir}/config/checkstyle.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    classpath = files()
}
```

And `checkstyle.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">

    <module name="TreeWalker">

        <module name="NeedBraces">
            <property name="tokens" value="LITERAL_CASE, LITERAL_DEFAULT"/>
            <property name="allowSingleLineStatement" value="true"/>
        </module>

    </module>

</module>
```

Running `gradle checkstyle` gives me following error:

```
Executing external task 'checkstyle'...
:app:checkstyle FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkstyle'.
> Unable to create a Checker: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Property 'allowSingleLineStatement' in module NeedBraces does not exist, please check the documentation

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

If I remove line:

```
<property name="allowSingleLineStatement" value="true"/>
```

it works. But reading the [documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_blocks.html#NeedBraces), first version should work too.

It happens similar with:

```
<module name="EmptyCatchBlock">
    <property name="exceptionVariableName" value="expected|ignore"/>
</module>
```

that throws me:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkstyle'.
> Unable to create a Checker: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate EmptyCatchBlock
```

What am I doing wrong or in what way am I missunderstanding the docs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At the time of this writing, Gradle [uses Checkstyle 5.9](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/f9485b40d979aefcddb496d654c454da3d5ac0a3/subprojects/code-quality/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/quality/CheckstylePlugin.groovy#L22) by default. The `allowSingleLineStatement` property was only [added in Checkstyle 6.5](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.5). So, you should be able to get this working by using a newer Checkstyle version like this:

```java
checkstyle {
    configFile = file("${project.rootDir}/config/checkstyle.xml")
    toolVersion = '6.7'
}
```

Unfortunately, the Checkstyle documentation is not versioned, so the Website always has the latest docs only, which makes it hard to figure stuff like this out.

Comment: Note that I had to precede the path of `configFile` with the `file` keyword, but the solution worked. Thank you very much, Thomas.

Comment: Yup, `configFile` is a `File`; updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: tried this solution, but IDEA shows me that
`Error:(12, 0) Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method toolVersion() for arguments [6.7] on project ':app'.`

Comment: @pratt That is a different problem / should be a new question. Maybe you forgot to apply the Java plugin, or you have a really old version of Gradle.

Comment: @Thomas, yea, you're right. Btw I figured out what was the problem. I was trying to specify `toolVersion` property as part of the Checkstyle task rather than CheckstyleExtension (means `task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) { }`)  vs `checkstyle { }`). See to compare the API: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.CheckstyleExtension.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.html